# I want to show any selected item from CheckedListBox in a ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have a windows form application that contains one "CheckedListBox" named "ChkBox1"  and it contains this items (Blue, Red, Green, Yellow).

The form contains also an empty "ListBox" named "LstBox1".

I want when i check any item from "ChkBox1" it add to "LstBox1" and when i unchecked it from "ChkBox1" it removed from "LstBox1".

I think i should use "ItemChecked" event but i don't know how can i detect if the item checked or not and add it to another list.

This is my try:

```
        private void ChkBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChkBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            listBox1.Items.Add(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);
        else if (ChkBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
            listBox1.Items.Remove(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    }
```

but it add the item when i unchecked it not when i check it.

and this is another try:

```
        private void ChkBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ChkBox1.GetItemChecked(e.Index) == true)
            listBox1.Items.Add(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);
        else if (ChkBox1.GetItemChecked(e.Index) == false)
            listBox1.Items.Remove(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void ChkBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState .Checked)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(ChkBox1.Items[e.Index]);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you .. but why you didn't make the else statement easiest

Comment: @Ahmed.Marzouk Yes you are right. I haven't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

The "ItemChecked" will send you an "ItemCheckEventArgs" that contains both the old and the new value.
It also contain the index of the value that has changed.
You can also check the "CheckedItems" property to get every checked items :

```
    private void ChkBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        LstBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in ChkBox1.CheckedItems)
            LstBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: @Ahmed.Marzouk Sorry, I didn't tried It but it shall work, what do you mean by "a bit error" ?